# malloc(5) = 5 chars or 5 bytes?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

String to be returned via function is 5 characters long

via `malloc()` 5 byte space has been reserved for the string.

```
char *Function () {
    char *data;
    data = malloc(5);
    strcpy(data, "aaabb");

    return data;
}
```

> code below prints `aaabb` as expected.

```
char *test;
test = Function();

printf("%s", test);
free(test);
```

without changing `malloc(5)`..

change the string to `aaabbbccc` : 9 characters long.

prints `aaabbbccc`

but `malloc(5)` should have only reserved room for 5 characters. not 9.

**Question 1** : what is the true meaning of

```
data = malloc(5);
```

**Question 2**: how to simply reserve room for exactly 5 characters ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You already reserve 5 `char`s. If you store more, you invoke undefined behaviour. It is not the gun's fault if you shoot your foot. What is unclear about the `malloc` man-page? Your beginner's C book? Any other resource about these basics in C?

Comment: There are very few targets for which the size of a character is not exactly one byte.

Comment: @BrianCain: There are absolutely **no** targets where `char` is **not** exactly a byte. But characters can be more than a byte on many platforms (e.g. all modern POSIX systems).

Comment: But I don't think that the OP will ever use them. This is theoretical only and makes problem more complicated for the beginner as it actually is. @Brian Cain how many times did you program targets with the char != byte (in the last 10 years).

Comment: @LightGreen suppose you book 5 theatre seats for your party of 6. It can happen there is no contention for the seat you didn't book, but if there is, trouble will follow. Be safe and book the correct number of seats (and hope that the nearby party has not underbooked and is already occupying one of them, or arrives later and one sits down in your lap).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You allocated space for 5 bytes (and a `char` is by definition 1 byte), but wrote more than 5 bytes.  C doesn't prevent you from writing outside the bounds of allocated memory or an array.  If you do, you invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With undefined behavior, anything can happen.  Your code may crash, it may output strange results, or (as in your case) it may appear to work properly.  Later on, a seemingly unrelated change such as adding an unused local variable or a `printf` for debugging can change how undefined behavior manifests itself.

Regarding you specific example, the string `"aaabb"` actually consists of 6 bytes: 5 for the characters in question, plus one more for the null byte that signals the end of the string.  So for this string you would need to `malloc(6)` to get enough space for it.  Similarly with `"aaabbbccc"`, you need 10 bytes allocated instead of 9.

Answer (score 6):

In the language of the C specification, bytes and `char`s are *the same thing*. So the answer to the question in the subject line is: both.

As for your second question, if you attempt to store more than 5 bytes in the allocated space that's only 5 bytes in size, the behavior of your program is undefined. Don't do that. The string `"aaabb"` is 6 bytes in size, since C strings are null-terminated (the sixth byte is the null character, with value 0).

Comment: Characters are not guranteed to be a byte. A character is not the same as the `char` type.

Comment: might want to add that a *byte* doesn't have to have 8 bits, so often *octet* is used for 8bit units to avoid confustion.

Comment: @Olaf, but a byte is exactly a `char`, so that's the correct answer to the subject line.

Comment: (still I smell our "old friend" again, now trying something different from CGI....)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I did not say "byte" and `char` are synonyms. But e.g. modern POSIX systems don't restrict characters to a single `char`. The used UTF-8 encoding will use more than a `char` for characters other than the ASCII set.

Comment: @Olaf yes, so you're just nitpicking on the wording "*bytes and characters*" in this answer. Indeed, it should read "*bytes and `char`s*".

Comment: @FelixPalmen As a Ger**ä**n, you should be aware of non-ASCII characters:-)  It is not just nit-picking, but a relevant difference. A high-rep user should be aware of it and point it out in his answer.

Comment: @Olaf: 3.7.1 *character -
single-byte character <C> bit representation that fits in a byte*. I agree the usage is unfortunate, but in the language of the specification, *multibyte character* is the general term and *character* refers specifically to a single-byte one. POSIX mostly fixes this language to use *byte* where they mean it.

Comment: @R..: 3.7 has a wider definition of the term: "_<abstract> member of a set of elements used for the organization, control, or representation of data_". Yes, it is unfortunate they use the same term for both, the "class" and single-byte characters, but with UTF-8 (see 6.7.9p14) as standard input character set for e.g. gcc, the wider interpretation should be used. Either way, your answer is very explicit about `char` <=> character, which is not correct.

Comment: @Olaf: It's not worth arguing over. I hope you like the edit.

Comment: @R..: I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

From man(3) malloc:

```
   malloc() allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory is not cleared.  If size is 0, then malloc() returns
   either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().
```

Bear in mind that in C you might write more bytes into a buffer that it's allocated. In such case you will overwrite some memory, which may lead to program failure or even more interesting results.

It's well explained in the excellent article "Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit" by AlephOne.
http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

Answer (score -1):

Normally if you just want a few characters (less than 1000 on a modern system) you simply declare them on the stack. malloc() is for large allocations, or storage that needs to persist after the function has returned

Comment: There is no stack in the C language. It is an irrelevant and not required implementation detail.